# java certificate verify failed

Tags: java, certificate, verify

I need to verify the leaf certificate using itsparent certificate.
I got 2 certificate from bing.com, when I used the Java API it success.

But in my App, I have not got the whole certificate, Only can got the Values of the part of the certificate. When I pick up the Values of the certificates and verify by myself , it failed.

Please help me find out what's wrong with my code, here is my code:

```
package net.laixiong;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class certVerify {
    private static Certificate CACert;
    private static Certificate[] certs;

    private static String TBSCertificate = "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";
    private static String pkInfoOfString = "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";
    private static String sigValue       = "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";

    static void sigVerify1() throws IOException, CertificateEncodingException {
        URL destinationURL = new URL("https://www.bing.com");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        certs = con.getServerCertificates();
        X509Certificate x509cert = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
        CACert = certs[1];
        byte[] b = x509cert.getTBSCertificate();
        b[0] = (byte) ~b[0];
        try {
            PublicKey pkOfCa = CACert.getPublicKey();
            x509cert.verify(pkOfCa);
            System.out.println("true");
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e2) {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }

    static void sigVerify2() throws InvalidKeySpecException {

        try {
            PublicKey pkOfCA = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(pkInfoOfString)));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pkOfCA);
            byte[] tbsHashValue1 = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(sigValue));

            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] tbsHashValue2 = messageDigest.digest(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(TBSCertificate));

            System.out.println(Arrays.equals(tbsHashValue1, tbsHashValue2));

        } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CertificateEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        sigVerify1();
        sigVerify2();
    }
}


//C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJIDEACommunityEdition2020.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56057:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJIDEACommunityEdition2020.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\myIDEAWorks\mySpecial\target\classes;C:\Users\lihong\.m2\repository\redis\clients\jedis\3.6.1\jedis-3.6.1.jar;C:\Users\lihong\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\lihong\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-pool2\2.9.0\commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\lihong\.m2\repository\net\sf\opencsv\opencsv\2.3\opencsv-2.3.jar;C:\Users\lihong\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.4\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\lihong\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\9.4.1208.jre7\postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar net.laixiong.certVerify
//        true
//        false
```

Added after I resolve the problem.

Thanks @dave_thompson_085, I found the corrent method in Signature API , my problem been resolved.
So the code like this :

```
PublicKey pkOfCA = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(pkInfoOfString)));
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initVerify(pkOfCA);
sig.update(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(TBSCertificate));
System.out.println(sig.verify(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(sigValue)));
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You can't verify the whole certificate unless you have the whole certificate. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421: they have the TBS and signature, which is sufficient given you know the sigalg (and for X.509 that's inside the TBS _as well as_ outside) and key

Answer (score 0):

Basically dupe [How to use x509 public key to verify a signed/hashed Alexa request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709994/how-to-use-x509-public-key-to-verify-a-signed-hashed-alexa-request-body) and more (across several Stacks) linked at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87006/why-is-data-signed-with-sha256-rsa-pkcs-and-digest-signed-with-rsa-pkcs-differen/#87022 .

First of all, the *better* way to verify a signature 'manually' is to use the `Signature` API as designed:

```
        PublicKey pkOfCA = KeyFactory...generatePublic... // as now
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(pkOfCA);
        sig.update(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(TBSCertificate));
        System.out.println(sig.verify(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(sigValue)));
```

However, if you insist on doing it with the 'backwards Cipher' method, you must do the ASN.1 DigestInfo DER encoding or decoding yourself; this amounts to adding or checking and removing a prefix that depends only on the hash algorithm used, as shown in e.g. [PKCS1v2.2 = RFC 8017 section 9.2 'Notes'](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#page-47). Specifically, either compare the 'decrypted' value to the concatenation of the appropriate prefix plus the actual hash value, or remove that prefix from the 'decrypted' value and compare only the remainder to the hash value.

Comment: Thanks you, I found the corrent method in Signature API , my problem been resolved.