# Signature Verification in Java for RSA SHA-256

Tags: java, rsa, signature, sha256, verification

**EDIT - Updated with full SAML**

I'm trying to verify a signature I receive from a SAML Response in Java.  The SAML Response is validated by samltool.io, but I am having a difficult time with the Signature class in java.  No matter what I try, it's returning false.  I have properly canonicalized my XML and I am able to successfully generate the correct MessageDigest with what I have in my content String.  Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.  Here is my code:

```
public class SigVer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        System.out.println("Initialized");
        
        String pubKeyStr = "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";
        
        byte[] certBytes = pubKeyStr.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(certBytes));
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);

        PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

        String content = "<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" Destination=\"http://10.100.1.123:8080/identityiq/external/registration.jsf\" ID=\"id130347804157883831058335572\" IssueInstant=\"2023-01-20T19:39:44.049Z\" Version=\"2.0\"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\" Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity\">http://www.okta.com/exk81ebtt38SLQ3I65d7</saml2:Issuer><saml2p:Status><saml2p:StatusCode Value=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success\"></saml2p:StatusCode></saml2p:Status><saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\" ID=\"id1303478041593882583231621\" IssueInstant=\"2023-01-20T19:39:44.049Z\" Version=\"2.0\"><saml2:Issuer Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity\">http://www.okta.com/exk81ebtt38SLQ3I65d7</saml2:Issuer><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified\">matt@revnatech.com</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer\"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter=\"2023-01-20T19:44:44.049Z\" Recipient=\"http://10.100.1.123:8080/identityiq/external/registration.jsf\"></saml2:SubjectConfirmationData></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore=\"2023-01-20T19:34:44.049Z\" NotOnOrAfter=\"2023-01-20T19:44:44.049Z\"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>http://10.100.1.123:8080/identityiq/</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=\"2023-01-20T19:39:44.049Z\" SessionIndex=\"id1674243584047.1963093145\"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement><saml2:Attribute Name=\"email\" NameFormat=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified\"><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"xs:string\">matt@revnatech.com</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute></saml2:AttributeStatement></saml2:Assertion></saml2p:Response>";
        
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(content.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        
        System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(digest)));

        String signature = "laE5splYJDi8uoMbbQ1tq8bWHPotfZW/aoJ1psWQkuzgc6wS0XS71MIFM9fcZ7rFQEGUWw0GXR6cy/nyDkCaEOH7o+VvKaainpKSktVrAbBtomWIkFx65AsDbHdcN0CZXIz57yRzzfFWjks+fYEHoEM48/HkB8brFxiiyJ17GEd96O7DErlCxen4W874/uOOneEZYBxXtcZnqQylJjgen3C7VyeQATK1AnGba6TK7cdClJjBDapmo/VnWBP6ovH8ZbATdd6u8au1xBqXBu/a+DLwFIdmd2TdDWmT0mkzz/MqdfCtP8W5nOk3UU9ZwfHzSBaQrWH3/mdIgqh8V57BMw==";
        
        try {
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(content.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            boolean result = sig.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            
            System.out.println("Returning " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My SAML Signature block is as follows:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
            <ds:Reference URI="#id130347804157883831058335572">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces>
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
                <ds:DigestValue>
                    1jaT9pnWmUCL0+atOcxHZ2yxhL5XOIhhHaK3Oz0gDWY=
                </ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
            laE5splYJDi8uoMbbQ1tq8bWHPotfZW/aoJ1psWQkuzgc6wS0XS71MIFM9fcZ7rFQEGUWw0GXR6cy/nyDkCaEOH7o+VvKaainpKSktVrAbBtomWIkFx65AsDbHdcN0CZXIz57yRzzfFWjks+fYEHoEM48/HkB8brFxiiyJ17GEd96O7DErlCxen4W874/uOOneEZYBxXtcZnqQylJjgen3C7VyeQATK1AnGba6TK7cdClJjBDapmo/VnWBP6ovH8ZbATdd6u8au1xBqXBu/a+DLwFIdmd2TdDWmT0mkzz/MqdfCtP8W5nOk3UU9ZwfHzSBaQrWH3/mdIgqh8V57BMw==
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    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
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
```

I have tried decrypting the SignatureValue with the PublicKey to retrieve what's in the DigestValue, but the value I retrieved when doing that didn't match up.  This is what I tried when attempting that:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);     
System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))));
```

Comment: You should always explicitly set the character encoding when using `String.getBytes`, but in several places you are not, like `content.getBytes()`. I don't know if that accounts for the problem though. We'll probably need a complete example of the problem include public keys and actual data.

Comment: I went ahead and updated all instances of getBytes() (I'll also update my code in the initial post.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to have changed anything.  I'll see about getting shareable SAML that I can post here.  I appreciate your insight!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have updated my code with a public-appropriate SAML Response (The canonicalized SAML minus the Signature block is stored in the content String, and the Signature block is listed below the code).  As before, I'm able to calculate the digest appropriately, but I'm still seeing a "false" return from sig.verify.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: in the general case charset matters, but base64 is designed very intentionally to use only characters in _all_ known character encodings, and in fact invariant in all charsets practically used in Java.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: The fact that the character exists in the charset is not the issue, it's the encoding into bytes that differs. The encoding of "a" is one byte in UTF-8, two bytes in UTF-16 and four bytes in UTF-32.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong in two ways.

First, in XMLdsig, which SAML uses, the 'real' signature (here the RSA signature) is not over the data or even the data hash as such. Rather, the hash of the data is placed in Reference.DigestValue, and the publickey signature is computed over the *SignedInfo* element, which *includes* that DigestValue, canonicalized. Conversely validation checks both that the signature matches the SignedInfo and that the DigestValue in the (or each) Reference matches the (related) data. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/#sec-Processing .

Second, the 'backwards RSA' `Cipher` in Java -- "encrypting with the privatekey and decrypting with the publickey" -- is not correct RSA signature; [this is a mistake](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/#159289) made back in the 1990s that has never been corrected, apparently for compatibility. Correct PKCS1v1-style signature, now retronymed RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 as referenced in [that same spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/#sec-PKCS1), is four steps:

1. hash the data
2. encode the hash (1) in an ASN.1 DigestInfo
3. pad (2) with 01 FF... 00
4. take (3) as an integer and modexp with the private exponent

Verification can be done by repeating 1-3 and comparing to the result of modexp-public which reverses 4 OR reversing 4 and 3 (remove 01 ...) AND 2 (split apart the ASN.1) before comparing to 1. Java's backwards `Cipher` only does 3 and 4 on the 'encrypt' side and 4 and 3 on the 'decrypt' side leaving you to do 2, as well as 1 *on the SignedInfo per above*.

This part is a very common mistake; see my list over at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87006/why-is-data-signed-with-sha256-rsa-pkcs-and-digest-signed-with-rsa-pkcs-different plus
[java certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121290/java-certificate-verify-failed)
[How to use x509 public key to verify a signed/hashed Alexa request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709994/how-to-use-x509-public-key-to-verify-a-signed-hashed-alexa-request-body)

Comment: Thank you for the information @dave_thompson_085.  I have read through the links you have provided, and ultimately landed on this Oracle article: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/dig-signatures.html
Is using the java.security.Signature class wrong for XMLdsig? I tried updating my signature String to contain the canonicalized XML for SignedInfo, but then I ran into "java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 2526 but was
 expecting 256". I will work on using the classes mentioned in the Oracle article in the meanwhile. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes `Signature` with the correct scheme, as in your code, is correct. That error sounds like you're trying to use the SignedInfo as the _signature_. I said the signature is computed _over_ (or _on_) the SignedInfo -- that means the SignedInfo is used as _data_, which in the Java API means it is passed to `sig.update`. The _signature_ (passed to `sig.verify`) is, as you already had, the value in SignatureValue de-base64-ed.